# How can I merge arrays and get acess for fields of both arrays Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to merge both arrays and get acess to field from the both of these models' field. How can I achive this? Now I have two model `Name` nad `Gender` and  i want all male names correlate and all female names correlate to female gender.

**The supoused output is:**

```
print (Name(name:'John', name:'Mike': [Gender(gender: 'male')], Name(name: 'Kate'), Name(name: 'Kate') : [Gender(gender: 'female')]))`
```

The code:

```
   void main() {
  List<Name> names = <Name>[Name(name:'John'), Name(name: 'Kate'),Name(name:'Mike'), Name(name: 'Kate') ];
  List<Gender> gender =<Gender>[Gender(gender: 'male'), Gender(gender: 'female')];
  List<Person> person = <Person>[Person(gender_id: 1, name_id: 1),Person(gender_id: 2, name_id: 2), Person(gender_id: 1, name_id: 3), Person(gender_id: 2, name_id: 4) ];

names.forEach((el){
  gender.where((elem) => elem.gender == el.nameId.compareTo(person.where(element) => element.)
}
}                 
 class Name{
   final int? nameId;
   final String? name;
   Name({this.name, this.nameId});
 }
 class Gender{
   final int? genderId;
   final String? gender;
   Gender({this.gender, this.genderId});
 } 
class Person{
  final int? gender_id;
  final int? name_id;
  
  Person({this.gender_id, this.name_id});
}
```

DartPad link - https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true

I am trying to assign elements from one models to elements from another elements based on it's name and gender, using `forEach()` and `where()` method. How can I achive it?

Comment: This seems confusing. You want to have two lists: males names and females names. But there is no way to know whether the name belongs to a female or male person (as defined in your example).

Comment: Thank you,  @Nicks101 I was given such example and data and I thought that I am too stupid to figure it out hehe. Can I ask you another question? If i create the third class which will be contain the ids from the both of models, can I  get acess by this way?

Comment: What ids are you referring to? A third model (say Person) containing name_id and gender_id. Then sorting all the male names and female names (assuming there is only two gender in your example). This could work I think.

Comment: yes, @ Nicks101 ,  i was thinking about it, thanks you. But I don't get how I can filter all classes and get their fields. I edited my question and now I am edited my code in question. Can you help me? I confused what I should iterate first/ May be i use the wrong method for iterating, In JS we have includes and fine methods but I don't know if such methods are presented in Dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign ids while creating instances because with ids only we are comparing.

I made some modifications with creating instances.

```dart
void main() {
  List<Name> names = <Name>[
    Name(name: 'John', nameId: 1),
    Name(name: 'Kate', nameId: 2),
    Name(name: 'Mike', nameId: 3),
    Name(name: 'Kate', nameId: 4),
  ];
  List<Gender> gender = <Gender>[
    Gender(gender: 'male', genderId:1),
    Gender(gender: 'female', genderId:2)
  ];
  List<Person> person = <Person>[
    Person(gender_id: 1, name_id: 1),
    Person(gender_id: 2, name_id: 2),
    Person(gender_id: 1, name_id: 3),
    Person(gender_id: 2, name_id: 4)
  ];

  /// <---- main solution
  final Map<int, List<int>> name_id_list = {};

  for (final g in gender) {
    for (final p in person) {
      if (g.genderId == p.gender_id) {

        name_id_list[g.genderId!] = name_id_list[g.genderId] == null
            ? [p.name_id!]
            : [...name_id_list[g.genderId]!, p.name_id!];
      }
    }
  }

  name_id_list.forEach((k, v) {
    print('for gender id $k, name ids are: ');
    for(final value in v){
      print(value);
    }
    print('\n');
  });
}
```

This is the console output:

```dart
for gender id 1, name ids are: 
1
3


for gender id 2, name ids are: 
2
4
```

Now, `name_id` 1 and 3 are `John` and `Mike`.
They have `gender_id` 1 in `Person` class.

So you have a list of names with any gender you specify in `Person` class.